# php как получать данные класса пользователя из сессии?

Tags: php, ооп, mvc, сессия

Пишу сайт в качестве обучения, использую модель `MVC`. У меня есть объект класса `User`. После авторизации данные сохраняются в сессии:

```
$user = new User($userData);
$_SESSION['user'] = serialize($user);
```

Подскажите, как теперь правильнее реализовать доступ к классу в приложении? У меня есть два варианта в голове:

1. На каждой странице, где понадобится класс, доставать объект из сессии.

   $user = unserialize($_SESSION['user']);
2. Создать статический синглтон типа `CurrentUser`, при запуске приложения инициализировать его и уже его использовать.

Понимаю, что первый вариант плохой. Второй вроде подходит, но по ощущениям кажется каким-то странным.

Comment: Однозначно второй вариант.

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков спасибо, значит, пока буду делать второй ) Думал, 
 может есть еще какой-то способ, который мне не пришел в голову и который везде используется =).

Comment: Синглетоны разные нужны, они разные важны ;) Как контекст работы приложения они могут использоваться, и их доступность в этом случае играет на руку.

Comment: Создать класс , но не синглтон. Просто сервис в контейнере.